# Change position on the graph screen gnuplot in bash script

Tags: scripting, display, gnuplot

i have a script in bash that read the file Throughputtx.txt and print this information in a graph of GNUPLOT, but this graph goes to the left side of my screen and I want it to be printed in the center of my screen.

```
gnuplot --persist -e "set xlabel \"No. Payload\"; set ylabel \"Throughput TX [bps]\"; plot \"Throughputtx.txt\" using 1:2 title 'Throughput in TX' with lines"
```

Comment: It depends what Gnuplot terminal type you are using, I think: for `wxt` you can set the position explicitly e.g. `set term wxt position 600,800`. OTOH the legacy `x11` terminal type supports an oldschool `-geometry` specification on the command line.

Comment: use the instruction that you gave me in several places of the sentence but it did not work, I show an example:

gnuplot --persist -e "set xlabel \"No. Paquete\"; set term wxt position 600,800; set ylabel \"Throughput TX [bps]\";plot \"Throughputtx.txt\" using 1:2 title 'Throughput en TX' with lines".
The version of gnuplot is G N U P L O T
 Version 4.6 patchlevel 2    last modified 2013-03-14 
 Build System: Linux x86_64. Thanks

Comment: Sorry - in that case I don't know. Perhaps the capability was added more recently.

Comment: The solution is: gnuplot -geometry -380-190 --persist -e "set xlabel \"No. Paquete\"; set ylabel \"Throughput TX [bps]\";plot \"Throughputtx.txt\" using 1:2 title 'Throughput en TX' with lines"